# How to trigger redirect with react-testing-library and Next.js inside a test

Tags: typescript, routes, jestjs, next.js, react-testing-library

I am storing the url history in a hook within a context like this:

```
const HistoryContext = createContext({
  history: [''],
  back: (fallback: string) => {
    fallback;
  },
});

export const useHistory = (): HistoryContextReturnValue => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [history, setHistory] = useState<string[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHistory((prev) => [...prev, router.asPath]);
  }, [router.asPath]);

  const back = (fallback?: string) => {
    for (let i = history.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      const route = history[i];

      if (!route.includes('#') && route !== router.pathname) {
        router.push(route);
        const newHistory = history.slice(0, i);
        setHistory(newHistory);
        return;
      }
    }
    if (fallback) router.push(fallback);
  };

  return {
    history,
    back,
    router,
  };
};

export const HistoryProvider = ({
  children,
  ...historyProps
}: HistoryProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <HistoryContext.Provider value={historyProps}>
      {children}
    </HistoryContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useHistoryContext = (): HistoryContextReturnValue =>
  useContext(HistoryContext);
```

The hook returns the history array and the router.

I want to write a test that checks if the new route has been added to the history array. This is what i got so far:

```
describe('useHistory', () => {
  test('should add element to history on redirect', async () => {
    const { result } = customRenderHook<unknown, HistoryContextReturnValue>(
      () => useHistory()
    );

    result.current.router?.push('/hello');
  });
});
```

The push method is being called, but nothing happens to the array.

The "customRenderHook" looks like this:

```
const mockRouter: NextRouter = {
  basePath: '',
  pathname: '/',
  route: '/',
  asPath: '/',
  query: {},
  push: jest.fn(),
  //...Other mocks
};

//Other stuff

const customRenderHook = <T, T2>(
  hook: (props: T) => T2,
  options?: RenderHookProps<T>
): RenderHookResult<T, T2, Renderer<T>> => {
  const { wrapper, formValues, router } = options || {};
  let customWrapper = wrapper;
  if (!wrapper) {
    const Wrapper = ({ children }: { children?: ReactNode }) => {
      const methods = useForm<T>({ defaultValues: formValues });
      return (
        <RouterContext.Provider value={{ ...mockRouter, ...router }}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={defaultTheme}>
            <FormProvider {...methods}>{children}</FormProvider>
          </ThemeProvider>
        </RouterContext.Provider>
      );
    };
    customWrapper = Wrapper;
  }
  return renderHook<T, T2>(hook, { wrapper: customWrapper });
};
```

How can I trigger the useEffect and put a new element into the history array inside the test? And then check in the test that the array was updated?

Comment: Can you show the full code for your `useHistory` hook?

Comment: Just added it :)